# Tailwind CSS not recognized in VSCode IDE for Angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, sass, tailwind-css

I've installed Tailwind CSS in my Angular project successfully, [following these simple steps in the official documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular). It works: no errors on the `@apply` and `@tailwind` directives when running `ng serve`, but the IDE reports diagnostics on them in .scss files:

[image: Issue]

Including `@apply`.

I'm using the following VSCode extensions:

- Angular Language Service
- PostCSS Language Support
- Tailwind CSS IntelliSense

My `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,scss,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

These extensions solved the problem for some framework earlier.

Comment: It's a general warning from VSCode's Sass language server that it does not recognize the `@tailwind` directives. These warnings can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind [encourages you not to use SCSS and stick with plain CSS instead](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors) - this is just SCSS not knowing about Tailwind.  So you have two options:

- Switch your project over to just use plain CSS and everything will work fine.
- Keep SCSS and deal with these errors

Comment: I understand, but I'm using Sass mixins for customising the scrollbar (which uses both `scrollbar-x` and `::-webkit-scrollbar-x`), so it's being a bit convenient.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I tried out Tailwind on a project and really wanted to use SCSS for all the convenience factors, but it just got in the way. I ended up not writing much CSS anyway like Tailwinds wants you to do, but even when I did I could use the `@apply` to pretty easily make what I want which felt similar to SCSS's `@include` for mixins.  Overall I didn't really like Tailwinds since it made a mess of my HTML