# How to make vscode recognize Tailwind's @apply?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, configuration, tailwind-css

I am writing a Vuejs + Tailwindcss in pure CSS mode and everything works fine (i.e. the app works as expected from the code).

Since I use vscode I configured it according to the Tailwindcss recommendations and I have Intellisense working fine.

One thing that is an eyesore is that directives are highlighted by vscode as `Unknown at rule @tailwind`

[image: "Unknown at rule @tailwind" warning in vscode]

Same with `@apply` (the Tailwind `@apply`, not the abandoned CSS one).

Is there a way to fix this?

---

*Note: [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76745060/tailwind-css-not-recognized-in-vscode-ide-for-angular-project) mentioned this issue but it was using Sass and the recommendation was to use pure CSS, which is my case.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the README, there is a Tailwind CSS language mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss#tailwind-css-language-mode):

> ### Tailwind CSS Language Mode
>
> An alternative to VS Code's built-in CSS language mode which maintains full CSS IntelliSense support even when using Tailwind-specific at-rules. Syntax definitions are also provided so that Tailwind-specific syntax is highlighted correctly in all CSS contexts.

Which can be enabled in your VSCode settings [as per the the README](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss#files.associations):

> Use the `files.associations` setting to tell VS Code to always open `.css` files in Tailwind CSS mode:
>
> ```json
> "files.associations": {
>   "*.css": "tailwindcss"
> }
> ```

You should also apply a `lang="postcss"` in your component `<style>` definition:

```
<style lang="postcss">
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! I added to your answer information about how to deal with components, feel free to modify if needed.